# symfony 2 annotation routes + group routing

Tags: symfony, routes

Is there any difference in using **annotation routes** or **group routes** in symfony 2 when it comes to performance, convenience, maintainability or in any aspect that would make the other more advisable to use?

Comment: What is meant by **group routing**?

Comment: I think there's no difference in production, as everything is loaded once an then cached

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [SensioFrameworkExtraBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/index.html), already shipped with Symfony 2. Having route names and paths in the same place of controller action is the right way to go. If you want to modify a path or action name simply go to that action, without editing `routing.yml`.

Then give a name to your "grouped routes" e.g. `bundle_controller` pattern or maybe `bundle_entity` (if controller is used for CRUD on a single entity):

```
# app/config/routing.yml
acme_hello_my_annotated_controller:
    resource: "@AcmeHelloBundle/Controller/MyAnnotatedController.php"
    type: annotation
```

Eventually prefixing all paths defined by annotations (add `prefix: /my/path/prefix`).

**EDIT**: don't know anything about performances. I'm talking only about convenience.